# can't access old Ubuntu HDD from new Linux Mint

Tags: hard-drive, linux-mint

I installed Linux Mint at new HDD.

And now want to move my work files from old hard drive to new.

I caught some trouble with this, I can't access this disk now.

But all was correct during installation (connection was established and worked perfect).

Here is my `lsblk`:

```
nazar_art@nazar-art-System-Product-Name ~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1   3,8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1   3,8G  0 part /media/nazar_art/8BAA-7FA6     // usb driver
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk                                // new HDD
├─sdb1   8:17   0   6,5G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 459,2G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0 149,1G  0 disk                                // old HDD
```

It can see my usb driver from which was installed Mint. But now it doesn't see old HDD.
Any suggestion?

**Update:**

I can only create new partition.

It shows unallocated disk.

[image]

I not sure that this new partition doesn't damage information... ?

Any suggestion?

A little bit more information:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /media/8BAA-7FA6
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0 464.8G  0 part /
├─sdc2   8:34   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdc5   8:37   0  1022M  0 part [SWAP]

nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00060485

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ sudo file -s /dev/sda
/dev/sda: x86 boot sector, code offset 0xb8
```

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: You could try to use gparted to check the partitions on sdc.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I misunderstand your suggestion? How gparted help me solve this issue?

Comment: If gparted will show the partitions of the old hdd, you can start mounting them. If it doesn't, it will propably show you some error details that will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I updated question

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` and `sudo file -s /dev/sdc` (assuming the old drive shows up as /dev/sdc; you may want to use one of the links under e.g. /dev/disk/by-id instead).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I updated question